# How can I code the Bernstein operator in Mathematica?

Tags: function-construction, arguments

Given a function $f(x) \in C[0,1]$, we define the $n$th *Bernstein Operator* $T_n$ by

$(T_nf)(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)t^k(1 - t)^{n - k}$.

I'm trying to code this in *Mathematica*, but I don't see how it can be done to take an unknown function as an argument. My current working code is

```
b[f[x_]_, n_, t_] := Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*f(k/n)*t^k*(1 - t)^(n - k), {k, 0, n}]
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone offer a way to take an undefined function as an input?

**Edit**: Though the code below in the comments works spectacularly, the code also works as-is, so long as one remembers to change $f(k/n)$ to $f[k/n]$, so that *Mathematica* knows to evaluate $f$ at $k/n$.

Comment: `bop[n_Integer, f_, t_] := Sum[Binomial[n, k] Function[t, f][k/n] t^k (1 - t)^(n - k), {k, 0, n}]`, and then try `bop[5, Exp[t], t]`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Also for reference: `BernsteinBasis[]` is built-in, so you can modify my code to shorten it further.

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 1):

Using a slightly different notation, consistent with [mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernsteinPolynomial.html) and [literature](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2016.12.075)

```
ClearAll[BernsteinOperator];
BernsteinOperator[n_Integer][f_, x_Symbol] := Sum[
  Function[x, f][i/n] BernsteinBasis[n, i, x]
  , {i, 0, n}
  ]

PiecewiseExpand[BernsteinOperator[2][a Exp[b x], x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@{
   Exp[x],
   BernsteinOperator[9][Exp[x], x]
   }
 , {x, -0.5, 1.5}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , PlotStyle -> {Gray, Red}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]